# Pyton2.7 Dot serpenstky triangle Tkinter

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

For my homework I have to create a program that maps dots to a Tkinter window, and creates a serpenstky triangle out of it. I can create it easily with lines, but I dont understand how I am supposed to get the math to work with dots.

My main question is how would I create a full object with dots using math in python for Tkinter?

```
from Tkinter import *
from random import randint

# the 2D point class
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self,x = 0.0 ,y = 0.0): 
        self._x = float(x)
        self._y = float(y)

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self):
        self._x = x

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self._y

    @y.setter
    def y(self):
        self._y = y
  #parts from previous program that I left in here just in case  
    def __str__(self):
        return '(' + str(self.x) + ',' + str(self.y) + ')'
    def dist(self,other):
        return ((self.x - other.x)**2 + (self.y - other.y)**2)**0.5
    def midpt(self,other):
        x=float((self.x + other.x)/2)
        y=float((self.y + other.y)/2)
        return Point(x,y)

# the coordinate system class: (0,0) is in the top-left corner
# inherits from the Canvas class of Tkinter



class chaosGame(Canvas):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Canvas.__init__(self, master, bg="white")
        self.colors = ["black"]
        self.radius = 0
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

    def plotPoints(self, n):
        min_x = 10
        min_y = 0
        k=1
        max_x = 600
        max_y = 520
        mid_x = (min_x + max_x)/2
        mid_y = (min_y + max_y)/2
        x1 = 3**k-1
        y1 = 3**k-1
        for i in range(n):
            point = Point((x1), (y1))
            self.plot(point.x, point.y)
            k+= 1


    def vertPoints(self, n):        
        topPoint = Point((300), (0))
        leftPoint = Point((0), (510))
        rightPoint = Point((590), (510))
        self.vplot(topPoint.x, topPoint.y)        
        self.vplot(leftPoint.x, leftPoint.y)
        self.vplot(rightPoint.x, rightPoint.y)

    def vplot(self, x, y):
        color = self.colors[randint(0, len(self.colors) - 1)]
        self.create_oval(x, y, x + 10, y + 10, fill= "red")           

    def plot(self, x, y):
        color = self.colors[randint(0, len(self.colors) - 1)]
        self.create_oval(x, y, x + self.radius, y + self.radius, fill=color)



##########################################################


WIDTH = 600
HEIGHT = 520
# the number of points to plot
NUM_POINTS = 50000

# create the window
window = Tk()
window.geometry("{}x{}".format(WIDTH, HEIGHT))
window.title("Triangles")
# create the coordinate system as a Tkinter canvas inside the window
s = chaosGame(window)
# plot some random points
s.plotPoints(NUM_POINTS)
s.vertPoints(3)

# wait for the window to close
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: create a line one pixel long, or use an oval, or an image that is 1x1.

Comment: how would I create a line with dots? I can do it using just straight up lines, but idk how itd work with a 1x1 dot

Comment: You don't create a line with dots. I suggested using a line that is one pixel long to simulate a dot.

Comment: What is a "Serpentsky" triangle? O_o

Comment: Infinite Recursive triangle

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_triangle

Comment: Idk, i cant get it working no matter how I do it